# Google Sheets - Set row number based from another cell value, inside the formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to set the value of the row, from another cell

For example, this `H186 cell`, if I put a value in the cell A1, like `200`, then the value would be `H200`

Something like this:
Assuming that A1 cell has a different value

```
=arrayformula(B2:B186&H2:H186) ===> =arrayformula(B2:B186&H2:H(A1))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a string first in another cell and pass this cell from a dynamic range( Data > Named ranges in Menu).

example: you have Column A random numbers, in Column B you can pass any value in B1. In B2 string value and the formula cell, indirect function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `INDIRECT` doesn't accept "`&`" inside, so I had to create 2 Named Ranges. Many thanks!
`=arrayformula(indirect(Teste)&indirect(Teste2))` How I did